# How to pass an object to the variables of the c# model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm reading a data from the InfluxDB database. The result of this query is of the object type and I need to pass this data to a module that has two variables.

Model:

```
 public class DashboardViewModel
 {
      public string time { get; set; }
      public string valor { get; set; }
 }
```

Async task in which I do the query:

```
public async Task<List<Serie>> ConsultaBD()
{
    var _client = new InfluxDb("http://host:8086/", "***", "***");
    List<Serie> series = await _client.QueryAsync("dbName", "SELECT T_PV FROM TFA WHERE time >= '2019-05-21' and time < '2019-05-22'");            

    return series;
}
```

IActionResult where I pass the data to a model:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
     DashboardViewModel DatosParaMostrar = new DashboardViewModel();

     DatosParaMostrar.time = ConsultaBD().Result[0].Values[0][0].ToString();
     DatosParaMostrar.valor = ConsultaBD().Result[0].Values[0][1].ToString();

     return View(DatosParaMostrar);
}
```

Data returned "QueryBD().Result[0].Values" is an object like this:

```
data->
       [0]->
             [0]= {21/05/2019 0:00:03}
             [1]= 586.5
       [1]->
             [0]= {21/05/2019 0:00:03}
             [1]= 575.4
       [2]->
             [0]= {21/05/2019 0:00:03}
             [1]= 595.5
       [3]->
             [0]= {21/05/2019 0:00:03}
             [1]= 584.25
       [4]->
             [0]= {21/05/2019 0:00:03}
             [1]= 583.625
       .......
```

with this code I only pass the first data, how could I pass all the data the object has?

Comment: if you want to get all data, then probably you should make your model as `list`, if then, loop through your `result` and assign to your model list.

Comment: `ConsultaBD()` will return a collection of `Serie`. In your code you're calling `ConsultaDB` twice and retrieving the same result. This will hit the database twice. Instead, store the results in-memory (i.e. `var result = await ConsultaDB()`, then as @NnN suggests, iterate over the list and build your model.

Answer (score 1):

You should `await` your `ConsultaBD` call:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    DashboardViewModel DatosParaMostrar = new DashboardViewModel();

    var result = (await ConsultaBD()).First();
    DatosParaMostrar.time = result.Values[0][0].ToString();
    DatosParaMostrar.valor = result.Values[0][1].ToString();

    return View(DatosParaMostrar);
}
```

If you want to display all retrieved data, not only first one then you should populate a list of your `DashboardViewModel` and pass it to your view:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{        
    var results = await ConsultaBD();
    IList<DashboardViewModel> model = results.Select(x => new DashboardViewModel {
         time = x.Values[0][0].ToString(),
         valor = x.Values[0][1].ToString()
    }).ToList();        

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: note the `async` keyword added to the action signature: `public async Task<IActionResult> Index() { ... }`

Comment: in the second code is necessary a loop?  Because if it is not necessary just take the first two values

Answer (score 0):

Model:

```
public class DashboardViewModel
{
    public string time { get; set; }
    public string valor { get; set; }
    public List<DashboardViewModel> lstDashboardviewModel {get; set; }
}
```

IActionResult:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{

    DashboardViewModel DatosParaMostrar = new DashboardViewModel();

    foreach(var data in ConsultaBD().Result){
        DatosParaMostrar.time = data.Values[0].ToString();
        DatosParaMostrar.valor = data.Values[1].ToString();
        DatosParaMostrar.lstDatosParaMostrar.Add(DatosParaMostrar);
    }        

    return View(DatosParaMostrar);
}
```

In your `view` do iteration of the list in the `model` and bind accordingly.